# Future real conditional (also first conditional ) in a reported speech: was or were?

Tags: tense, reported-speech, conditionals

**Questions:**

Q1:

When using a first real conditional in a reported speech, it has to be backshifted. But I don't know whether to use: **was** or **were**?

Q2:

Are the tenses of the italic words (*met* and *went*) in Example 1 and Example 2 correct?

**Examples:**

Example 1:

If he is friendly when we meet tomorrow, I will make friends with him.

> I thought if he **was/were** friendly when we *met* the next day, I would make friends with him.

(I am describing my thoughts in advance of the meeting that is now in the past.)

Example 2:

If he is doing his work when I go to his place, I will visit next time.

> I thought if he **was/were** doing his work when I *went* to his place, I would visit him next time.

(I am describing my thoughts in advance of the visit that is now in the past.)

Answer (score 1):

1. I think that, to be strictly correct, you should use *were*, but *was* would be acceptable in colloquial speech.
2. It depends whether the event you are thinking about has happened or not. Are you describing your thoughts in advance of a meeting that is now in the past, or speculating about a future event?

Neither sentence is quite idiomatic. I suggest *...I would visit him another time* (when he is not busy).

Comment: [English teachers at American schools have been known to mark various hypothetical uses of **was** as “wrong”, saying that it “should” be **were**.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/429514/2637) But as a Brit, I think those teachers are simply *wrong*. You might as well claim that in order to be "strictly correct", the text should be expanded to *I thought if he were **to be** doing his work when...*. But again, this isn't true. As with most contexts where people ask about Past Perfect / Simple Past here, it's often "possible" - but rarely *necessary* - to use such more complex verb forms.

Comment: My examples are my thoughts in the past. In Example 1, I hadn't met the new person yet, and I like friendly people, so at the time, I thought, "If he is friendly when we meet tomorrow, I will make friends with him." I am describing my thoughts in advance of the meeting that is now in the past. I wanted to know how to backshift it in this case. Do I have to use "were"? The backshift doesn't seem hypothetical to me. And Example 2 doesn't seem hypothetical, either.

Comment: _I thought that, if he was/turned out to be friendly when we met the next day, I would [hope to] make friends with him._

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for your reply. So, if it is a thought in the past (like the case in my previous reply), which is not hypothetical, we use "was" instead of "were", right?

Comment: But (despite what Fumblefingers says) see [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+thought+if+it+were&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20if%20it%20were%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20thought%20if%20it%20were%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The statistics are not that useful since it doesn't tell us whether it is a subjunctive mood or backshifted first conditional. My question is if I want to write a reported first conditional, what should I use: was or were? For example, At the time, I was about to go on a blind date. I thought, "If she is my type, I will ask for her number." Let's change it to reported speech: "I thought if she was/were my type, I would ask for her number." Should it be "was" or "were"?

Comment: If you look at the examples as well as the statistics, you will find _I thought if it [a sofa] were here I could see the TV better. - I thought if it were a musical, people would look at it again. - I thought if it were worth much..._